# React native image pixel are breaking

Tags: android, react-native

Image pixel is breaking;

> I’m using React-Native Image
> Original Image Size: 1644 × 16932 pixels

> Original Image---- Rendered Image
> [image: Original Image---- Rendered Image]

```
Image style
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: 3600,
              resizeMode: "cover",
              flex: 1,
            }}
```

> React Native Environment Info:

```
System:
      OS: macOS 12.5
      CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M2
      Memory: 88.53 MB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 16.16.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
      npm: 8.11.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 2022.11.14.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: DriverKit 22.1, iOS 16.1, macOS 13.0, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335
      Xcode: 14.1/14B47b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3 
      react-native: 0.59.9 => 0.59.9
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

```
1)
        style={{
          resizeMode: "contain",
          flex: 1,
        }}

2)    
        style={{
           width: "100%",
           height: "100%",
           resizeMode: "contain",
        }}
```